# 2D Binpacking efficiency on a bin-level

Tags: optimization, packing-problem

I want to minimize the amount of unused space in a binpacking problem. I keep seeing binpacking being described as using the least amount of bins possible. Example (emphasis mine):

> assign each item to a bin such that **number of total used bins** is minimized

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/

Would minimizing the amount of bins guarantee the least amount of waste? And if so, is there a minimum amount of bins (based on the algorithm used, not necessarily the one from the above link) that we need to use before it is efficient? Or is binpacking "by default" efficient in minimizing waste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your bins have capacity $c$, you have a total weight $w$ to put in the bins and you use $n$ of them. Then the wasted space $W$ is :
$$W = \text{total bins capacity} - \text{weight put into them} = nc - w$$
Since $c$ and $w$ are fixed, minimising $W$ amounts to minimising $n$, since each is an increasing function of the other. Intuitively, using more bins adds to the total bins capacity without changing how much you use it, so you effectively increase the wasted space.

Comment: So the best way to minimize waste would be to essentially use the last "bin" that you need as efficiently as possible? Since reducing the amount of bins used isn't really an option (you need it to do the job, can't lower the amount of packages). I guess in that case minimizing bins used and waste is the same.

Comment: Well yes, it's about using *every* bin as efficiently as possible. You could use a greedy algorithm but with something like $c = 10$ and weights $8, 1, 9, 2$, you would fill the first bin with $8, 1$ and then be left with $9$ and $2$ which need two more bins.

Comment: In my case it is impossible to "split" anything, so it seems a decent binpacking algorithm is the best way to solve my problem. Now I just need a way to make it prefer results where the wasted area tends towards the shape of a package (or I need to let the user drag and drop to make manual changes).

Thanks. I will mark the answer as correct when possible.